# Ошибка компиляци error #2144: Type error: pointer expected

Tags: c

В попытках реализовать функцию сложения двоичных чисел столкнулся с ошибкой  #2144: Type error: pointer expected. в этих двух строках.

> ```
>   int bit1 = ls1[i] - '0'; 
>   int bit2 = ls2[i] - '0';
> ```

Все кавычки и точки с запятой расставлены, стало быть, требуется указатель, но я, к сожалению, не могу понять, где и как он должен быть установлен

```
char sum(char s1, char s2) {
 int len1 = strlen(s1);
 int len2 = strlen(s2);
 // Выровняем длины строк
 char ls1 = len1<len2 ? s1 : s2;
 char ls2 = len1<len2 ? s2 : s1;
 for (int i = strlen(ls1); i < strlen(ls2); ++i) 
     ls1 = '0'+ls1;
 char result;
 int carry = 0;
 for (int i = strlen(ls2) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int bit1 = ls1[i] - '0'; 
    int bit2 = ls2[i] - '0';
    char sum = (bit1 ^ bit2 ^ carry) + '0';
    result = sum + result;
    carry = (bit1&carry)|(bit2&carry)|(bit1&bit2);
 }
 if (carry) result = '1' + result;
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас же объявлен

```
char ls1
```

Что может означать `[i]` у символа? Вероятно, вы хотели работать со строками - но тогда это `char*` (или `const char*`, если строка не изменяется).

То же относится у вас и к аргументам функции, только вот учтите, что в C складывать строки, как вы вроде бы хотите сделать, например, в `ls1 = '0'+ls1;`, нельзя.

В целом у вас код из-за непонимания того, как работают строки, содержит массу ошибок, которые простой заменой `char` на `char*` не исправить. Так что я бы рекомендовал - предваряя ваш вопрос "что делать?" - почитать учебники/Интернет о строках в языке C.